# How to get mat-checkbox checked value if used in ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to get all checkboxes which are checked and perform some function on them.

```
<div class="outerdiv" *ngFor="let item of items">
<mat-checkbox>Hello</mat-checkbox>
<div>

<button (click)="filterSelectedItems()"></button>

filterSelectedItems(){
let outerdiv = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.outerdiv');
 for(let i = 0; i < outerdiv.length; i++){
      let option = outerdiv[i].querySelector('mat-checkbox');
      if(option.checked){
        this.filterItem+=option.innerText;
      }
}
```

Comment: Please paste full .ts code

Comment: @GangadharGandi ihave updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: show the items array declaration and the element declaration as well.

Comment: its an array of string but i think items array doesn't matter it is just for purpose of looping for several times for label of checkbox @GangadharGandi

Comment: Okay, Paste ViewChild declaration as well. i.e element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can get Total** working example in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efyvdr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Your html is**, and `onChange` of checkbox `getCheckbox()` event fire. here we are passing template reference variable `#checkBox`.

```
<div *ngFor ="let item of items">
     <mat-checkbox #checkBox [value]="item" (change)="getCheckbox(checkBox)">  
          {{item}} 
     </mat-checkbox>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let checkedItem of checked">
     <span> selected Key is: <strong>   {{checkedItem.value }} </strong> : 
            <strong> {{checkedItem.checked}} </strong> 
     </span>
</div>
```

**You can get array of** `#checkBox` in `component.ts` file using `@ViewChildren()` and `QueryList` like this...

```
  @ViewChildren ('checkBox' ) checkBox:QueryList<any>;
    checked = [];
    items =['one','two', 'three', 'four'];

  getCheckbox(checkbox){
      this.checked = []; // resetting each Time new event is fire.
   // filtering only checked vlaue and assign to checked variable.
    const checked = this.checkBox.filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked);

   // then, we make object array of checked, and value by checked variable  
      checked.forEach(data => {
           this.checked.push ({
               'checked' : data.checked,
               'value':  data.value
           })
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get the checked value on triggering the `change` event of the `mat-checkbox`.

```
<div class="outerdiv" *ngFor="let item of items">
  <mat-checkbox [checked]="item.value" (change)="getCheckedValue($event)">Hello</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```